# Bootstrap "form-floating": label has weird margins when inside "row"

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to use `form-floating` to get the floating label look, but the margins get messed up when I put the `form-floating` class inside a `row`.

For comparison, this is without the `row` (label looks good):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-floating col-6 mb-3 mt-3 ml-auto">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is with the `row` - notice how the "Name" label now touches the left side of the input:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-floating col-6 mb-3 mt-3 ml-auto">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this minimal example, `row` might not be needed, but I'm trying to place the form on the left column while putting other content on the right. How can I get this to work?

Comment: row in bootstrap has a negative padding... hence its placed on the line, rather than having padding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the grid styles.
See:

```css
.row {
    /* --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem; */
    /* bs gutter overwrites the form gutter! */
    --bs-gutter-y: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: calc(var(--bs-gutter-y) * -1);
    margin-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
    margin-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) * -.5);
}
```

Solution that worked on my browser:

Overwrite the gutters on your containing div element back to their original value.

```html
<div class="form-floating col-6 mb-3 mt-3 ml-auto gx-1">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
  <label for="name">Name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess that with the gx-* is enough (but I don't know why)

Comment: I added this CSS, rather than change all my HTML: `.row > .form-floating > label {
 margin-left:0.75em;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-floating col gx-1">
  <input id="Name" required placeholder="Name" class="form-control" />
  <label class="text-muted" for="Name">First name</label>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide first name</div>
 </div>
```